# Larger picture in minipage, [scale=..] not effective

Tags: graphics, minipage

I try to make the last picture in this minipage larger with the [scale=..] code, but it is not working.
I hope it does not have to do with the original view of the picture, so it can be fixed using a latex code.

Here is how i coded in the latex file:

```
\begin{figure}[h]  
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{PEO.JPEG}  
  \small\caption{PEO}  
  \label{PEO}  
\end{minipage}%  
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}  
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{PCL.JPEG}  
  \caption{PCL}  
  \label{PCL}  
\end{minipage}%  
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}  
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[scale=1.5][width=\linewidth]{polymersomePEOPCL.JPEG}  
  \bigskip   
  \caption{Polymersome of block co-polymer PEO-PCL}  
  \label{PEO-PCL}    
\end{minipage}    
\end{figure}%
```

And this looks like this in the PDF file. Not very nice, because of the smaller last picture.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Whre is the `scale`?

Comment: See edited message. I deleted it in my own file because it was not working.

Comment: You can't just add more `[..]`. You have to seperate the options by a comma: `[scale=1.5, width=\linewidth]`. Of course in this case it still wouldn't work because you don't allow it to be wider than `\linewidth`. Try it without the `width=\linewidth`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.